# Vue-Router - Переход на дочернюю страницу по умолчанию

Tags: vue-router, vue3

Сделано по документации, но видимо я что-то не понял :(

router/index.js

```
const routes = [
  ......
  
  {
    path: '/contractor',
    name: 'contractor',
    component: () => import('../views/ContractorView.vue'),
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        name: 'default',
        component: () => import('../components/contractors/AppSearch.vue')        
      },
      {
        path: 'card/:objId',
        name: 'card',
        component: () => import('../components/contractors/ContractorCard.vue'),
      }
    ]
  },
................
]
```

В шаблоне ссылка:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'contractor'}">BlaBla</router-link>
```

При нажатии на нее выходит только содержимое ContractorView.vue. Но если обновить браузер, то появляется содержимое компонента AppSearch.vue, как и написано в документации.
В консоли никаких ошибок.

Как добиться, чтобы дочерний компонент выводился без перезагрузки страницы?

== Обновлено
Когда публиковал - не обратил внимание на формат строки со ссылкой - исправил.

Похоже, что проблему решил путем "через колено" - заменил ссылку на

```
<router-link to="/contractor/">BlaBla</router-link>
```

Т.е. проблема решена, но вопрос остался - как вызвать дефолтную страницу с именованным параметром

Comment: `{ path: '*', redirect: '/contractor' }` возможно это вам нужно) + возможно у вас пустой роут `path: '',` + дефолтный роут нужно в конце прописывать, так как, если я не ошибаюсь, сортировка массива роутов с начала списка

Comment: В конец списка - не помогло.

Comment: Звездочка тоже не помогла, ни в конце ни в начале списка. Хотя звездочка - это не пусто, но все равно попробовал